# MongoDB - The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' threw an exception

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm just wondering if anyone has ever seen this exception? I'm using the C# driver and have successfully run this code on many servers. We are seeing this on one particular production server.

The first time I see this is on the first insert into a new collection. After that it seems to occur each time I call InsertBatch for that collection.

I've successfully called InsertBatch on other collections successfully during the same run.

Error**** Message = The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' threw an exception., Stack Trace =    at MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId.GenerateNewId()
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IdGenerators.BsonObjectIdGenerator.GenerateId(Object container, Object document)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.InsertBatch(Type nominalType, IEnumerable documents, MongoInsertOptions options)

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Can you reproduce it? Could you debug it with the driver source code?

Comment: We did reproduce it and unfortunately it's in a customers environment so we can't debug it but that's actually a good idea. I can at least debug it in my environment to see what is happening in the code.

Comment: I found that it is reproducible with a one line program:  
  
   ObjectId id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();  
  
The error returned is:  The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId' threw an exception

Comment: Can you step into the code though? That's a method that you should be able to step into. Is there an inner exception?

Comment: Inner exception is "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" - I'm building the driver now so I can step through the code

Comment: (I'm very interested to hear what you find is causing this ...)

Comment: Tracked it down to a known Mongo issue with the C# driver:  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-573

Answer (score 0):

Check your inner exceptions. Since Mongo does not implement FIPS and that's mandatory in some operative system configurations, you might get this error even with authentication disabled while trying to read or generate an ObjectId (since they have an encrypted id value). To solve this problem either replace your encrypted "_id" field values on your collection, or modify the Windows registry to allow applications not implementing FIPS.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same error on PHP today. Found out that it was a known issue (see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPC-460). I know this is C# but maybe it is a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting with BSonId serialization which has implemented at 2013 from someones
https://github.com/SharpRepository/SharpRepository/issues/56

In my case downgrading Asp.net Core 3.0 to 2.2 has worked out.

I think mongodb.csharp driver needs to System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters reference

at 3.0 version

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2611

And an update will come on second separate of 2019
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/pull/372