# Cannot convert to type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer`1[System.String]'

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the mongoDB driver for C# and I'm having issues trying to do some queries due to the Serialization/Deserialization. As far as I could understand I'm not able to serialize an Int32 field to string.

***System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'US.EndPointTests.AdditionalFunctionalities.TestingObjectTypeSerializer' cannot be converted to type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer`1[System.String]'.***

This is my collection:

```
private class contactos
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

    [BsonSerializer(typeof(TestingObjectTypeSerializer))]
    public string telefono { get; set; }
    [BsonSerializer(typeof(TestingObjectTypeSerializer))]
    public string telefono2 { get; set; }

    public string direccion { get; set; }
    public string direccionNormalizada { get; set; }
    public string[] maestroTipoContacto { get; set; }
    public string maestroCanalEntrada { get; set; }

    [BsonSerializer(typeof(TestingObjectTypeSerializer))]
    public string nota { get; set; }
    public string cifnif { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("particion")]
    [BsonSerializer(typeof(TestingObjectTypeSerializer))]
    public string particion { get; set; }

    public DateTime fechaCreacion { get; set; }
    public DateTime fechaModificacion { get; set; }
    public string nombreNormalizado { get; set; }

    public string[] tipoMaestroContacto { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to delete one document from the DB using:

```
            returnDictionary = GetContact();                

            string particion = (returnDictionary["particion"].ToString());

            var builder = Builders<contactos>.Filter;

            var filter = builder.Eq("particion", Int32.Parse(particion));

            var DeleteOne = collection.DeleteOne(filter);
```

But I'm receiving this error:

**System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'US.EndPointTests.AdditionalFunctionalities.TestingObjectTypeSerializer' cannot be converted to type 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer`1[System.String]'.**

This is my custom serializer (I tried some different approaches here but none of them worked):

```
public class TestingObjectTypeSerializer : IBsonSerializer
{
    public Type ValueType { get; } = typeof(string);

    public object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var bsonType = context.Reader.CurrentBsonType;
        switch (bsonType)
        {
            case BsonType.Null:
                context.Reader.ReadNull();
                return null;
            case BsonType.String:
                return context.Reader.ReadString();
            case BsonType.Int32:
                return context.Reader.ReadInt32().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            default:
                var message = string.Format("Cannot deserialize BsonString or BsonInt32 from BsonType {0}.", bsonType);
                throw new BsonSerializationException(message);
        }
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            context.Writer.WriteString(value.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            context.Writer.WriteNull();
        }
    }

    private static object GetNumberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context)
    {
        var value = context.Reader.ReadInt32();

        switch (value)
        {
            case 1:
                return "one";
            case 2:
                return "two";
            case 3:
                return "three";
            default:
                return "BadType";
        }
    }
}
```

}

And the collection schema:

[Collection Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj0oO.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `TestingObjectTypeSerializer` should be `public class TestingObjectTypeSerializer : IBsonSerializer<string>`

Comment: mind the `<string>` at the end

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56004350/914284